# How to change TextDecoration color in WPF TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, text-decorations

I am changing the color of the `TextDecoration` this way:

```
<Grid Background="{x:Null}"
      Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Style="{StaticResource SWMRegularTextBlockStyle}"
               Margin="0"
               FontSize="{DynamicResource RegularFontSize}"
               x:Name="tb" />
        <Line VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              Visibility="{Binding InStock, Converter={StaticResource ReverseBooleanToVisiblity}}"
              Stroke="Red"
              Margin="0"
              StrokeThickness="2"
              X1="1"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=tb, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</Grid>
```

But when `Text` has two lines it fails. Please help me to change the color of [TextDecoration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations.strikethrough(v=vs.110).aspx). 
Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I want `TextBlock` foreground and strike-through line in different colors.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource  SWMRegularTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0" FontSize="{DynamicResource RegularFontSize}" x:Name="tb" >
   <TextBlock.TextDecorations>
        <TextDecoration Location="Strikethrough">
            <TextDecoration.Pen>
                <Pen Brush="Red" />
            </TextDecoration.Pen>
        </TextDecoration>
    </TextBlock.TextDecorations>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Exactly what I just searched for.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that you're overlaying a line on the text.  When the text wraps you need to create another line which is not going to be easy.

You can solve this by not using the line at all but instead using a specific pen for the TextDecoration of the strikethrough in the code behind.

[Answer found here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/FillthestrikethroughdecorationwithasolidcolorbrushinC.htm)

```
    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fill the overline decoration with a solid color brush.
        TextDecorationCollection myCollection = new TextDecorationCollection();
        TextDecoration myStrikeThrough = new TextDecoration();
        myStrikeThrough.Location = TextDecorationLocation.Strikethrough;

        // Set the solid color brush.
        myStrikeThrough.Pen = new Pen(Brushes.Red, 2);
        myStrikeThrough.PenThicknessUnit = TextDecorationUnit.FontRecommended;

        // Set the underline decoration to the text block.
        myCollection.Add(myStrikeThrough);
        tb.TextDecorations = myCollection;
    }
```

And then simplify your XAML.  Remove the Line control, and add `Loaded="WindowLoaded"` to your Window